# Set LookUp Value using Jquery in Default List Forms

Tags: jquery, lookup-column

I am trying to set Look Up Drop down using JavaScript/Jquery. I am able to set the value but while saving by default 1st option in drop down is Set.

Thanks in Advance...!!!

Comment: you have to set value in this format ->   12;#Value

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: item ID of the lookup value from where it actually exists and the value of that field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

native Javascript, no jQuery

```
function setOption( selector , value , allowMultiple ){
  var options=document.querySelector( selector ).childNodes;
  for(var i=0;i<options.length;i++){
    var option=options[i];
    if (!allowMultiple) option.removeAttribute('selected');
    if (option.getAttribute('value')===value || i===value+1) option.setAttribute('selected','selected');
  }
}

//set one value by name 
setOption( "select[title='Task Status']" , 'Completed' , false );

//set multiple values by number
setOption( "select[title='Task Status']" , 1 , true );
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below helped me to set the LookUp value of DropDown in default edit/new form of List

```
var ValuetoSet="test";
var FieldToSet = $('select[title="Customer ID"]');
$.each(dataClsField[0],function(){if($(this).text() == ValuetoSet) {
    dataClsField.val(this.value);
}});
```